# Update single column to have multiple rows from another table

Tags: sql-server

I use sql server 2017 and I have two tables (Project table) and (Students table) how to update students_group column at project table to have multiple students from student table.

Comment: please share some data and what you have tried, and what you expect

Comment: Project table has student_group column—>>students-group must contains 5 students from student table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need a student_group column in Stundents table also.
Eg: If the project have ID 1 in student_group column, then in Stundents tabel, in the same column you will have 1 for every student in the Project.